# Errors when importing lmfit in ipython

Tags: python, ipython, lmfit

I'm having problems importing lmfit in ipython.

Running ipython 2.30 with python 2.7.9:
importing lmfit produces two errors:
1)

```
/home/cfigura/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit/ui/ipy_fitter.py in <module>()
     14 # Handle the change in naming from 2.x to 3.x.
     15 if IPython.release.version_info[0] == 2:
---> 16     from IPython.html.widgets import DropdownWidget as Dropdown
     17     from IPython.html.widgets import ButtonWidget as Button
     18     from IPython.html.widgets import ContainerWidget as Box

ImportError: No module named html.widgets
```

If I try to re-import, that error disappears and  I get this:

```
In [2]: import lmfit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-58ac0858c54d> in <module>()
----> 1 import lmfit

/home/cfigura/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit/__init__.py in <module>()
     42 
     43 from .model import Model, CompositeModel
---> 44 from . import models
     45 
     46 from . import uncertainties

ImportError: cannot import name models
```

This error does *not* disappear on re-running the import.

If I do *not* use ipython but simply import into a normal python shell, I have no errors/problems.  Clearly there is some kind of conflict with ipython!

Has anyone seen something similar, or can point me in the correct direction to address this?  Mahalo!

Comment: If you installed IPython with apt-get, I think ensuring that `ipython-notebook` is installed should get you past that error. You might run into another problem, though - it looks like lmfit is assuming that anything running in IPython is running in a notebook.

Comment: Thomas K - installing ipython-notebook *did* resolve the issue.  I will do some additional testing to verify that lmfit functions properly, but the import has succeeded!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reposting as an answer:

The issue was that, on a Debian based system, `ipython` was installed but `ipython-notebook` was not. Installing `ipython-notebook` resolved this. If other readers run into this on Python 3, the package is `ipython3-notebook`.

There may be other problems with lmfit - it looks like the code assumes that anyone using IPython is using the notebook interface.